# Linked keywords are not expanded and embedded

Tags: dxa, keyword

SDL Documentation
**[About DXA's resolution of linked Components during publishing](https://docs.sdl.com/784837/696059/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/about-------------dxa-s-resolution-of-linked-components-during-publishing)**

We are using DXA 2.2 but want to expand and embed Keywords when publishing, there may be a lot of Keywords which could hurt performance if dynamically expanded when the page is requested.

The documentation indicates that expanded and embedded is the default, however when testing with Template Builder we see that the keywords are linked not embedded.

How do we change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether Keywords from a certain Category are embedded or not is based on whether said Category is "Publishable".

If not publishable, the Keywords will be embedded. If publishable, they will be expanded by the Model Service/Extension.

[image]